# How to copy .pem files to Typescript outDir

Tags: node.js, typescript

In my NodeJS project, written with Typescript, I am referencing a couple of `.pem` files to start an `https` server.

The problem is that after my code is compiled, the `.pem` files don't appear in the output directory.

How do I get them to appear in the file structure the same way as they are when it's in `.ts` form.

**Here is my `server.ts` code (snippet):**

```
..
let server: Server;
try {
  const options = {
    key: fs.readFileSync("./https/key.pem"),
    cert: fs.readFileSync("./https/cert.pem")
  };
  server = https.createServer(options, app);
} 
..
```

**For reference, here is my `package.json`**

```
{
  "name": "manicmusic-app",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "_server:run": "ntsc -p ./server && concurrently \"ntsc -w -p ./server\" \"nodemon --delay 10 dist/server_parent/server/bin/www.js\"",
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/common": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/compiler": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/core": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/forms": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/http": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/router": "^4.2.4",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^1.0.0-beta.5",
    "@types/body-parser": "^1.16.7",
    "@types/jsonwebtoken": "^7.2.3",
    "@types/mongoose": "^4.7.27",
    "angular2-jwt": "^0.2.3",
    "body-parser": "^1.18.2",
    "bootstrap": "^4.0.0-beta.2",
    "connect-mongo": "^2.0.0",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "easy-pbkdf2": "^0.1.2",
    "express": "^4.16.2",
    "express-session": "^1.15.6",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^8.1.0",
    "mongoose": "^4.13.4",
    "octicons": "^7.0.1",
    "rxjs": "^5.4.2",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.14"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "1.3.2",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/language-service": "^4.2.4",
    "@types/connect-mongo": "0.0.34",
    "@types/express": "^4.0.39",
    "@types/googlemaps": "^3.29.2",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.5.53",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.2",
    "@types/node": "^8.0.53",
    "codelyzer": "~3.1.1",
    "concurrently": "^3.5.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.6.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.1.0",
    "karma": "~1.7.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.1.1",
    "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.2.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "nodemon": "^1.12.1",
    "ntypescript": "^1.201706190042.1",
    "protractor": "~5.1.2",
    "ts-node": "~3.2.0",
    "tslint": "~5.3.2",
    "typescript": "~2.3.3"
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't think .pem files are supposed to be copied over like that

Answer (score 2):

## Solve by three steps

1. install cpx `yarn add cpx` or `npm i cpx`'
2. add to package.json under scripts object:

```
scripts: {
    "build": "tsc -p . && yarn run cp",
    "cp": "cpx ./src/ab.pem build/"
}
```

`cpx yourfile yourDestination`

3. done, when you run `yarn build` it'd automatically cp the file

Cheer!

Comment: this works but I had to add path with quotations like this:
`"cp": "cpx \"./src/cert/*.*\" \"dist/cert\""`

Answer (score 1):

There are two options to resolve your issue:

1. Post build script which will copy the files.
2. Create symlinks in output directory. Don't forgot add them to your git repo.

Do you need examples?

Comment: Yes I would love an example of link of what you mean by `1`,. 
And is `2` possible in Windows?

Comment: On windows it will be harder. Could you provide your package.json file?

Comment: Added package.json to question

Comment: 1. run npm install cpx
2. add "postbuild": "cpx ./https/key.pem <targetPlace> && cpx ./https/cert.pem <targetPlace>".